# DbgPrint() fails to print out strings but not numbers

Tags: windbg

I am working on a simple driver, currently I am at the very beginning with a simple callback installed with PsSetCreateThreadNotifyRoutine. In the callback function I call DbgPrint to print out the pid and process name:

```
DbgPrint("%.4x %s", ProcessId, GetProcessNameFromPid(ProcessId)); // dbgview shows nothing
```

If I remove the %s specificer it suddenly works:

```
DbgPrint("%.4x", ProcessId); // works
```

I am using dbgview to view debug messages, on Windows 7 x64. I have in the registry Print Debug Filter set to 0xF

Also I verified with windbg that returned pointer by GetProcessNameFromPid() is indeed points to the process name.

```
LPSTR GetProcessNameFromPid(HANDLE Pid)
{
    PEPROCESS Process;

    if (PsLookupProcessByProcessId(Pid, &Process) != STATUS_SUCCESS)
        return "????";

    return (LPSTR)PsGetProcessImageFileName(Process);
}
```

Comment: What **type** does `GetProcessNameFromPid` return?

Comment: It is defined as `LPSTR GetProcessNameFromPid(HANDLE Pid)`

Comment: GetProcessNameFromPid is not a standard Windows API. What does it do?

Comment: No it is not, I updated the question with the declaration.

Comment: Got the mistake! Apparently
PsGetProcessImageFileName() is not defined nowhere in my header files. My compiler did not complain about it neither my linker, but the latter took it as its return value was DWORD. Similar to when you call printf() without including stdio.h, some linker will deal with it.

Comment: Then, maybe delete the question.